# Writing a SpooledTemporaryFile to disk

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am working on a `Strawberry` API service that accepts documents. I receive files and process them like so:

```
import typing
import strawberry
from strawberry.file_uploads import Upload


@strawberry.input
class FolderInput:
    files: typing.List[Upload]


@strawberry.type
class Mutation:
    @strawberry.mutation
    async def read_file(self, file: Upload) -> str:
        return (await file.read()).decode(...)
```

According to the API docs: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile

The `file` parameter has a member attribute of type `SpooledTemporaryFile` which looks like a `tempfile`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile

How do I write that file to disk?

Comment: Have you tried calling the `rollover` method?

Comment: This works for me, thank you!